# Solve constrained equation with 12 variables

Tags: r, constraints, equation

I am struggling with something that should be a simple task. I want to solve this equation to find all the possible solutions `(for Xi, i=1...12).`

`Y = a*X1 + b*X2 + .... + z*X12`

(I have 98 fixed values for Y, so I will repeat the procedure 98 times)

subject to:

`Sum of Xi = 1 (for i=1,...,12)`, `Xi (for i=1,...,12)` varying from *0.001* to *0.5*, with steps of about *0.001* (no higher precision).

I tried to decompose the problem but it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: code-wise, can you be more explicit about what you have actually tried?

Comment: I didn't try to code this because I have no idea how to do it. I was trying to approach the problem from a much more rude way, such as built in a Matrix all the possible Xi combo according to my constraints, to select those equations equating my Y. Of course it was a stupid try, I cannot build such a big matrix. It would have 2.44e+32 values.

Comment: This doesn't look like an R question.  I'm not sure if it's a math question or a stats question -- it's not very clearly posed.

Comment: It seems an R question to me. But I am new on StackOverflow so I am sorry if I have been inaccurate. I want to find all the possible solutions for Xi (I=1...n) such that Y is equal to 0.03, say, letting the code choose Xi values from a predetermined set of values, let's say from W = matrix(c(seq(0.001,0.5,0.001)), ncol = 1) constrained to Sum of Xi = 1 (i=1,...,12). Is it possible ?

Comment: So if I am not missing something, you have two equations for 12 different variables which leaves us with 10 degrees of freedom. You probably can loop through values between 0 and 0.5 for all X to find which ones work

Comment: The problem is that you are going to end up with quite a lot of answers, which can be up to 9.765625e+26 (500 ^ 10), where 500 is number of options for each Xi based on your step.

Comment: I do not think R can support that. This problem arise from another one that I could not solve. The origin of the matter is that I have to Minimize a custom function I wrote to compute Value-At-Risk as a function of weights. It is not a normal VAR, is a rolling measure reduced to a single value. The aim is to find the optimal set of wi (i=1,..,12) that minimize the the VAR measure for several target return, subject to constraints, such as sum of wi =1. I opened another topic on this but I could not find a way, that's why I am trying to find all possible weights to apply the function to those.

Comment: Formatted description.